# Implementing DDR In/Out DQ Pin for DDR3 SDRAM on Xilinx Spartan-6 FPGA

Tags: fpga, sdram, ddr3

I’m currently working on a project that involves interfacing a DDR SDRAM (Micron MT41J128M16) with a Xilinx Spartan-6 FPGA. I have implemented a controller. I’m looking for guidance on how to properly implement the DDR inout DQ pins for the SDRAM. What timing constraints should I set up in my FPGA design to ensure that data is properly captured and transmitted to the DDR SDRAM? Are there any Xilinx-provided IP or libraries that can simplify the DDR interface implementation?

Comment: Xilinx are now known as AMD, since AMD bought them out a while back. The ISE will have some built in IP blocks, have you checked that? Searching the AMD website provides various IP blocks for interfacing with RAM, I'm not sure what you're asking for exsaclty, but this link may help: https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/ddr3.html